# Почему создаётся текстовый документ?

Tags: c#, winforms, if

Я хочу отфильтровать какие-нибудь плохие, матерные слова в своей программе. Если такие слова написаны в Text Box, то программа не должна создавать текстовый документ и вписывать туда это слово. Моя программа замечает такие слова и выводит Message Box о том, что не надо писать такое слово и одновременно с этим, создаёт текстовый документ и пишет туда это слово, почему сразу же выполняется два оператора if?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GuiFolderCreator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string path = $"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\Desktop\\NewFolder";
    // Эти слова (поменял заместо матов)
        public string[] bad_words = { "noob", "bad", "bot" };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(Directory.Exists(path)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            else
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Папка уже существует. Вы хотите удалить её?", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Directory.Delete(path, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    ;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Папки не существует. Хотите создать её?", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }
                else
                {
                    ;
                }
            }
    // Та часть кода
            else
            {
          //Выполняет сразу же два оператора if (пробовал также else if; else)
                if (!File.Exists($"{path}\\TextDocument.txt"))
                {
                    foreach (string banword in bad_words)
                    {
                        if (textBox1.Text.ToLower().Contains(banword))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show($"Сам {banword} ^_^", "Ты чё совсем?", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }

                        if (!textBox1.Text.ToLower().Contains(banword))
                        {
                            File.Create($"{path}\\TextDocument.txt").Close();
                            File.WriteAllText($"{path}\\TextDocument.txt", textBox1.Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Текстовый документ уже существует. Вы хотите удалить его?", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        File.Delete($"{path}\\TextDocument.txt");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool found = false;
foreach (string banword in bad_words)
{
  if (textBox1.Text.ToLower().Contains(banword))
  {
    MessageBox.Show($"Сам {banword} ^_^", "Ты чё совсем?", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    found = true;
  }
}
if (!found)
{
  File.Create($"{path}\\TextDocument.txt").Close();
  File.WriteAllText($"{path}\\TextDocument.txt", textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, ты помог мне. Сейчас время пройдёт я тебя лучшим ответом сделаю

Comment: @JustChickNugget `File.Create` - лишнее. `WriteAllText` создаст файл автоматически, если его нет.

Comment: @aepot хорошо, учту